# Is a newline equivalent to && in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, control-flow

I'm very simply wondering if, in a bash script,
a new line is functionally 100% equivalent to `&&`?

e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

7z x "${file}"

mv "${file}" "${new_file}"
```

vs

```
#!/bin/bash

7z x "${file}" && mv "${file}" "${new_file}"
```

GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: `&&` only runs the command following it if the command preceding it succeeds. Thus

```
7z x "${file}" && mv "${file}" "${new_file}"
```

only renames the file if `7z` completes successfully, whereas

```
7z x "${file}"
mv "${file}" "${new_file}"
```

will run `mv` in all cases (and fail if `${file}` doesn’t exist).

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details (in particular, it describes how new lines are also not quite the same as  `;`).

Comment: Since`$file` is a parameter that should be `7z x -- "$file"` and `mv -- "$file" "$new_file"` (NB some people seem to think that `${var}` is equivalent to `"$var"`)

Comment: what if we add `set -e` at the beginning of the second example? Would it then behave the same as the first snippet?

Comment: Isn't that a good practice to put curly braces around vars? https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/why-you-should-put-braces-around-your-variables-when-shell-scripting

Comment: @s.k  Do both. Writing `$A` as `"$A"` prevents shell expanding `A` into multiple words. Writing `$A_B` as `${A}_B` prevents shell trying to expand an unknown variable `A_B` instead of expanding `A` and appending `_B`. Many of the extended expansions (array, substring, trimming) require the `{..}` to control the internal syntax.

Comment: @Meto not quite — `7z … && mv …` will only run `mv` if `7z` succeeds, but will continue running after `mv` if `7z` fails; whereas `set -e; 7z …; mv …` will exit if any command fails, including `mv`, and anything following `mv` won’t run if `7z` or `mv` fails.